# Windows Explorer Registry Keys

Tags: windows, registry

I am working on a simple utility which will show/hide file extension from right click menu , it would be easy for user to toggle file extension on/off , anyway i should add that option to right click menu in both desktop and inside any explorer window , i knew how to do that in desktop via that reg key : HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell , but i do not know the corresponding key for windows explorer right click menu , i`d really appreciate it if someone could tell me where can i add items to windows explorer right click menu . and thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the sidebar on the lower right.  There are many related questions having to do with the Explorer context menu.  Read them.

Comment: I tried that and even goolge , but i don`t know what to name what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` for the context menu displayed when there are no items selected.